# flutter: sending http request from flutter_background_service plugin

Tags: android, flutter, background-service

I am trying to send http request using dio in flutter background service but code is stuck at .get() keep awaiting without any exception (like timeout exception), I put print before and after the request the one before is printed but the next one is not.
note: same request (same host) works in app.

```
void main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await initializeService();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

    // initialise the plugin of flutterlocalnotifications.
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flip = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    // app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable
    // resource to the Android head project.
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    //var IOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();

    // initialise settings for both Android and iOS device.
    var settings = new InitializationSettings(android: android);
    flip.initialize(settings);

  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'IQ_Pivot', // id
    'Afko Notification', // title
    description:
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.low, // importance must be at low or higher level
    
  );
  
  await flip
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      // this will be executed when app is in foreground or background in separated isolate
      onStart: onStart,

      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,

      notificationChannelId: 'IQ_Pivot',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'Afko Notification',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      
    ),
  );

  service.startService();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
onStart(ServiceInstance service) async{
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();



  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  api_service as = api_service(test: 1);
  await as.getStatueOfSensor("1",test: 2);

}

getStatueOfSensor: 
Future <String> getStatueOfSensor(String id , {int test = 0}) async {
    myDio.Response? response;
      print("background http in test = ${test+1}");  // this one is printed
      response = await dio!.get("/sensors/"+id.toString()+"?   username=${USER_NAME}&sys=${SELECTED_SYSTEM}");
      print("background http test is $response in test = $test"); this one is never printed
}
   

AndroidManifest.xml permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

I tried to make mqtt connection to handle notification from micro controller but it never connected then I checked the connection through http request; turns out it never connects to internet or something wrong else is happening.
I also tried workmanager plugin (didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

It is because background service can not get the instance of any library.

Create new instance of `Dio` and make API call with it.

```
final dio = Dio();

Future <String> getStatueOfSensor(String id , {int test = 0}) async {
   print("background http in test = ${test+1}");  // this one is printed

     ///NOTE: Pass your API full URL...
     var response = await dio.get("/sensors/"+id.toString()+"?   username=${USER_NAME}&sys=${SELECTED_SYSTEM}");
      print("background http test is $response in test = $test"); this one is never printed

      print(response.data);
  
  //return string whatever you want to return
  return '';
}
```